# What is the difference between difference-in-difference (DiD) and A/B testing?

Tags: difference-in-difference, ab-test

I am learning about difference-in-difference (DiD) methods and I find it similar to A/B testing.

What's the difference between these two testing methods?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only difference is what group's lexicon the term belongs to (DiD is the term used by economists, while A/B testing is the term used by software/UX). Both terms refer to randomized trials where the effect of an experiment is evaluated by measuring the difference in outcomes between a treatment and a control group.

Comment: I should add, difference-in-differences compares outcomes across *groups* and across *times*, not simply a difference *between* treatment and control groups as this answer suggests. If the only time period observed is the period in which treatment is in effect (i.e., posttreatment phase), then it is a posttest only evaluation. I would not suggest using the two techniques interchangeably. It is more than just a difference in nomenclature.

Comment: AB can be used to measures the difference between two randomly selected groups but does not consider other aspects of the individuals, while DiD considers the underlying characteristics of the individuals by using control variables. For example, if the two groups (control and test) where not selected randomly, we are incurring in selection bias. The use of DiD, with appropriate control variables (those that account for the selection in either group), correct the bias selection.